# Build Failure: Integration test fails on Jhipster generated project

Tags: jhipster, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running the following docker command on a gateway generated by jhipster project

```
.\mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
```

However, an error related to a failed integration test, here is the full trace:

```
    [ERROR] java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener: Provider reactor.blockhound.junit.platform.BlockHoundTestExecutionListener could not be instantiated
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Results:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  50.194 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-25T12:08:57+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) on project my-gateway: 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Please refer to D:\Work\S2M\monitoring_proj\myGateway\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
    [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
    [ERROR] java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener: Provider reactor.blockhound.junit.platform.BlockHoundTestExecutionListener could not be instantiated
    [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
    [ERROR] java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener: Provider reactor.blockhound.junit.platform.BlockHoundTestExecutionListener could not be instantiated
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:701)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:311)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:268)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1334)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1167)  
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:931)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)   
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
    [ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:152)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

when i skipped the tests with  the command:

```
.\mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild -DskipTests=true
```

but i want to know why does it fails the test in default?

Comment: You did not paste the most important part of the error, please edit your question and paste more.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453283/jhipster-7-1-0-failed-to-generate-gateway-provider-reactor-blockhound-junit-pl  Please check which flavor of java you are running and paste output of `java -version`

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build openj9-0.26.0, JRE 11 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210421_976 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - b4cc246d9
OMR      - 162e6f729
JCL      - 7796c80419 based on jdk-11.0.11+9)

Comment: OK, so you use J9 and this is not supported please install another JDK

Comment: okay i will install an other one

Comment: I get the same error when migrating from spring-boot 2 to spring-boot 3  with java 21

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I am migrating a reactive project generated by jhipster v7 to spring-boot v3.2.0 (inspiration from jhipster v8), the solution is to add `AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods` to both `maven-failsafe-plugin` and `maven-surefire-plugin`:

`<argLine>@{argLine} -XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods</argLine>`