# Jhipster Oauth2 + Keycloak User identity duplicated

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I am creating a new application with jhipster Oauth2.

Jhipster version: 7.2.0

I would wonder

1. Why did every microservices got duplicated user entity ?
2. Why do we need to sync with Keycloak user via UserService.syncUserWithIdP on every microservices ?

Example JDL:

```
application {
  config {
    baseName gateway 
    packageName com.gateway
    applicationType gateway
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven 
    clientFramework react 
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    testFrameworks [cypress,cucumber]
  }
  entities Blog, Post, Tag, Product
}

application {
  config {
    baseName blog
    packageName com.blog
    applicationType microservice 
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType h2Disk
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    enableHibernateCache true
    serverPort 8081
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    clientFramework react
    testFrameworks [cucumber]
    jhiPrefix blog
  }
  entities Blog, Post, Tag
}

application {
  config {
    baseName store
    packageName com.store
    applicationType microservice
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType h2Disk
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    enableHibernateCache true
    serverPort 8082
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    clientFramework react
    testFrameworks [cucumber]
    jhiPrefix store
  }
  entities Product

}


entity Blog {
  name String required minlength(3)
  handle String required minlength(2)
}

entity Post {
  title String required
  content TextBlob required
  date Instant required
}

entity Tag {
  name String required minlength(2)
}

entity Product {
  title String required
  price BigDecimal required min(0)
  image ImageBlob
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Post{blog(name)} to Blog
}

relationship ManyToMany {
  Post{tag(name)} to Tag{post}
}

paginate Post, Tag with infinite-scroll
paginate Product with pagination

microservice Product with store
microservice Blog, Post, Tag with blog

dto * with mapstruct
service * with serviceClass
```

I tried to search for explanation via https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2 but no luck at the moment.

Any help or support would be appreciated.

Thank you so much and Have a good day.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451382/jhipster-7-1-0-failed-to-use-jdl-import-throws-error-looking-for-otherentity-u this feature is controversial for me but I guess that the idea was to be able to build join queries with User

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I saw your comment. That said there is a restriction to sync all the User entities right?. In gateway, we sync via /api/account, but in microservices UserSerive.getUserFromAuthentication has not been called yet. So I think we have to sync it manually in microservices.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16074, but it's still under discussion.

Comment: Not really still under discussion, it's stale, feel free to enter the discussion to show your interest.